# Setting up AWS IAM for publishing .net Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There are many tutorials on publishing to AWS Beanstalk on windows using AWS Visual Studio SDK (2019). What is left out is setting up the permissions in AWS.

I have create a new account on AWS. I created a User Group and added a User to it.

My group has the following permissions:

[image]

but to no avail.

Current error:

User: arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/BeanstalkPublish is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-west-1:yyy:parameter/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version because no identity-based policy allows the ssm:GetParameter action

I am completely new to AWS.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) to your user or group:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:GetParameter",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want, you can replace `"*"` with `"arn:aws:ssm:us-west-1:yyy:parameter/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/*"` to limit the permissions to only the parameter you want.

Comment: Thanks but I have not been able to try it out. I have given up on beanstock and just using an ec2 instance.